# How can I copy data from a SQL_ASCII to a UTF8 postgresql db using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, character-encoding, sqlalchemy

I am writing a db data migration tool using SQLAlchemy's expression language as the basic tool.

My source database may be in UTF8, or it may be in SQL_ASCII. My target DB will always be in UTF8.

I'm using the psycopg2 driver in SQLAlchemy 0.6.6

My general migration process looks like this:

```
for t in target_tables:
    log.info("Migrating data from %s", t.fullname)
    source = self.source_md.tables[self.source_schema + "." + t.name]
    for row in source.select().execute():
        with sql_logging(logging.INFO):
            conn.execute(t.insert(), row)
```

If I don't set anything encoding-related on the engines, I get this when I iterate over the `select()` results:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I set `use_native_unicode=True, encoding='utf-8'` on the engines, I get this when I attempt to insert the new row:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (DataError) invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xeb6d20
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
 'INSERT INTO project_ghtests_survey000005.employees (first_name, employee_id) VALUES (%(first_name)s, %(employee_id)s)' {'first_name': 'Art\xebm', 'employee_id': '1234'}
```

#### Update details

To make inquires a bit quicker, here's the software stack in play:

- source_db encoding: `SQL_ASCII`
- target_db encoding: `UTF8`
- python 2.7
- sqlalchemy 0.6.6
- psycopg2 2.2.2
- PostgreSQL 8.2 server

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the solution was to set the connection client_encoding to 'latin1'

I accomplished this using a PoolListener like so:

```
class EncodingListener(PoolListener):

    def connect(self, dbapi_con, con_record):
        with closing(dbapi_con.cursor()) as cur:
            cur.execute('show client_encoding')
            encoding = cur.fetchone()[0]

        if encoding.upper() == 'UTF8':
            return

        dbapi_con.set_client_encoding('latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since UTF-8 is backwards compatible with UTF-8, why use `SQL_ASCII` isntead of `UTF8`?

I think your encoding problems are probably more along the lines of `latin1` or similar encodings. Not with `ASCII` to `UTF8`.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The DB is already in SQL_ASCII, I don't have a lot of say in that.

Comment: @Chris R: I mean that it doesn't matter if you specify `SQL_ASCII` or `UTF8` for the source database since `UTF8` is backwards compatible with `ASCII`.